# This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property. Parameter name: binding error in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I have tried to bind a datasource to a `DevExpress.XtraEditors.LookupEdit` at run-time. I tried this code, but am getting the following error:

> This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same property. Parameter name: binding.

Here is my code:

```
// Create an adapter to load data from the "Customers" table.
OleDbDataAdapter testcustomers = new OleDbDataAdapter(
"SELECT CustomerId, Customername FROM Customer WHERE CompanyId =" + TXE_CompId.Text, connection);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();  // Create a dataset that will provide data from the database.
testcustomers.Fill(ds, "Customer");  // Load data from the "Customers" table to the dataset.
// A BindingSource for the "Customers" table.
BindingSource binding_cust = new BindingSource(ds, "Customer");

CBL_SelectCustomer.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", binding_cust, "CustomerId");  // getting error on this line
// Specify the data source to display in the dropdown.
CBL_SelectCustomer.Properties.DataSource = binding_cust;
// The field providing the editor's display text.
CBL_SelectCustomer.Properties.DisplayMember = "CustomerName";
// The field matching the edit value.
CBL_SelectCustomer.Properties.ValueMember = "CustomerId";

// Add two columns to the dropdown.
LookUpColumnInfoCollection coll = CBL_SelectCustomer.Properties.Columns;
// A column to display the ProductID field's values.
coll.Add(new LookUpColumnInfo("CustomerName", 0));
```

How can this error be fixed?

Comment: at what line do you get the exception?

Comment: 6th line I mentioned in that code `CBL_SelectCustomer.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", binding_cust, "CustomerId"); `

Answer (score 14):

> Every Control can have only one binding at a time. It looks like you
>   already have a binding to the textboxes before and now when you try to
>   rebind it, it throws an error. You need to clear the old binding
>   before adding a new one.

Clear binding first and then add it to the control:

```
CBL_SelectCustomer.DataBindings.Clear();
CBL_SelectCustomer.DataBindings.Add("EditValue", binding_cust, "CustomerId");
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this before binding:

```
CBL_SelectCustomer.DataBindings.Clear();
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but in my case I kept getting that error because I had been calling a `form_load` event in de forms constructor (under `InitializeComponent();`, a mistake when copy pasting). That kept loading the form twice each time which isn't noticeable till you encounter funky behavior like this.
If that's your case, deleting that `this.Load += new System.EventHandler(Form1_Load)`  (or similar call) will help.