# Binding a DataGridView and Textbox to the same Datable gives me a 'two binding' error

Tags: c#, .net

I have two DataTables, and each one is bound to its own DataGridView and RichTextBox.

So for dataTable1, I have bound dgvFirstOne and rtbFirstOne.
For dataTable2, I have bound dgvSecondOne and rtbSecondOne.

Opening the form and using the DataGridViews work perfectly. No issue there. However, when I close the form (*this.close()*), I get the following error:

> 'This causes two bindings in the collection to bind to the same
> property.'

I suspect that this is because I have a richtextbox **and** a datagridview bound to the same datatable.

```
dgvFirstOne.DataSource = Form1.dataTable1;
rtbFirstOne.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataTable1, "DataColumn");

dgvSecondOne.DataSource = Form1.dataTable2;
rtbSecondOne.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataTable2, "DataColumn");
```

This strikes me as particularly odd, as in another form, I have a DataTable and a DataGridView and RichTextBox bound in the same manner, with no issues.

I have tried binding it this way as well, but with the same result:

```
this.bsFirstOne = new BindingSource();
bsFirstOne.DataSource = dataTable1;
rtbFirstOne.DataSource = bsFirstOne;
rtbFirstOne.DataBindings.Add("Text", rtbFirstOne, "Data", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
bsFirstOne.BindingComplete += new BindingCompleteEventHandler(bsFirstOne_BindingComplete);

this.bsSecondOne = new BindingSource();
bsSecondOne.DataSource = dataTable2;
dgvSecondOne.DataSource = bsSecondOne;
rtbSecondOne.DataBindings.Add("Text", bsSecondOne, "Data", true, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged);
bsSecondOne.BindingComplete += new BindingCompleteEventHandler(bsSecondOne_BindingComplete);
```

Does anyone know what's going on?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236318/this-causes-two-bindings-in-the-collection-to-bind-to-the-same-property-paramet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every control can have only on binding at a time.
That's why before assigning a binding source, just clear old binding using **Clear()** method:

```
dgvFirstOne.DataSource = Form1.dataTable1;
rtbFirstOne.DataBindings.Clear();
rtbFirstOne.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataTable1, "DataColumn");

dgvSecondOne.DataSource = Form1.dataTable2;
rtbSecondOne.DataBindings.Clear();
rtbSecondOne.DataBindings.Add("Text", dataTable2, "DataColumn");
```